# Best practices to model and table names

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to understand the rails conventions around model and table names. For example:

I have the following models:

```
class Blog < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :blog
  has_one :metric
end

class Metric < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
end
```

This generates the following tables:

```
blogs
posts
metrics
```

This can be confusing because metrics doesn't contain a namespace in the name (like `post_metrics`). Should I instead create a model `PostMetric` or perhaps change the name of the table with `table_name = 'post_metrics'`? Is there a clear rule here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure that `Metric` should only be related to `Post`, then `PostMetric` or `Posts::Metric` would be good solutions. For `Posts::Metric`, you can read more about namespacing ActiveRecord models for organization purposes [here](https://blog.makandra.com/2014/12/organizing-large-rails-projects-with-namespaces/).

If you think `Metric` could be used more broadly, you could leave it as is, but make the relationship [polymorphic](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) so that you can relate `Metric` to other models.

Also, it may make better sense to just embed the `Metric` data in the post itself by using a `jsonb` column (though this would make getting `Blog` level metrics more complex):

```
add_column :posts, :metrics, :jsonb, null: false, default: {}
```

Lastly, I would avoid leaving it as `Metric` and changing the table name.  This makes it hard to immediately know that `Metric` is in fact `post_metrics`.

Comment: `Post::Metric` would nest your class in another model which will give a bunch of bugs due to how constant lookup works. You really want to nest the model in a separate module.

Comment: This is no longer the case with the new Zeitwerk loader and a ruby patch in 2.5: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/44a2576f798b07139adde2d279e48fdbe71a0148

Comment: Thanks, good to know. You still have to configure the table name explicitly though.

Comment: Right, which may a good reason to use a different module since you would otherwise have the change the table name in each namespace model or make sure to include the method `self.table_name_prefix` in each namespaced model

Answer (score 0):

`PostMetric` is not namespaced. Its just a slightly more descriptive name than just `Metric`.

Namespacing is when you nest your models in a module for disambiguation or code organization:

```
# app/models/blogs/metric.rb
module Blogs
  # table name is blogs_metrics
  class Metric < ApplicationRecord
  end
end

# app/models/posts/metric.rb
module Posts
  # table name is posts_metrics
  class Metric < ApplicationRecord
  end
end
```

Note that the tables are named `plural_plural` - `blogs_metrics`. Rails automatically infers that the class is nested when the first "word" is plural.

There are no hard and fast rules when it comes to naming and code organisation. Its up to you as the author to make the most descriptive names possible without being excessively verbose.

Comment: The article you referenced is outdated since Ruby 2.5. It also referenced Rails Classic autoloading which has been replaced by Zeitwerk in 6.0